# Python convert list of tuples into single tuple

Tags: python, django, list

Is there a way to convert a list of tuples into a single tuple? I have received a list of tuples from cursor.fetchall() but would like to make this into a single tuple:

```
curr_table_columns = cursor.fetchall()
```

For example:

```
[(u'w_id',), (u'w_name',), (u'w_street',)]
```

becomes

```
[(u'w_id', u'w_name', u'w_street')]
```

Answer (score 6, accepted):

[With `itertools.chain`](https://docs.python.org/3/library/itertools.html#itertools.chain), it's trivial. `from itertools import chain` and you can do either:

```
[tuple(chain.from_iterable(curr_table_columns))]
```

or:

```
[tuple(chain(*curr_table_columns))]
```

The former is preferred for long or unbounded iterable inputs (though don't wrap in `tuple` for unbounded!); for a small input (particularly one that's already a `list` or `tuple`), the latter is slightly slower, but fine. Either one is going to be significantly faster than a genexpr and indexing for inputs of any size at all.

Comment: Thanks for your comment on my answer +1

Comment: @bernie: I just figured you'd edit yours; only posted my own because you deleted. :-)

Comment: No worries! :-)

Comment: You can also use: sum(tupleVar, ())

Comment: @shadow0359: Yeah, as mentioned, the scaling on `sum` for sequences is quadratic, where `chain` wrapped in `tuple` is linear scaling, so if you can't be 100% sure your inputs are tiny, you don't want to use `sum`. Even Python's [docs for `sum` basically say "I think you wanted `chain`"](https://docs.python.org/3/library/functions.html#sum).

Answer (score 2):

Try this:

```
a=[(u'w_id',), (u'w_name',), (u'w_street',)]

print [tuple([i[0] for i in a])]
```

Output:

```
[(u'w_id', u'w_name', u'w_street')]
```

Answer (score 2):

Not efficient*, but it is simple:

```
>>> ts = [(u'w_id',), (u'w_name',), (u'w_street',)]
>>> sum(ts, ())
('w_id', 'w_name', 'w_street')
```

So, just wrap it in a list if you must:

```
>>> result = [sum(ts, ())]
>>> result
[('w_id', 'w_name', 'w_street')]
```

*Warning: scales quadratically. Some might be inclined to let is slide for joining some column names into a single container. Definitely don't try to process millions of tuples this way.

Use `itertools` solution for linear time.

Comment: Note: [The `sum` docs](https://docs.python.org/3/library/functions.html#sum) themselves discourage using `sum` for this purpose (recommending `itertools.chain` instead). It works, but the scaling is terrible when the inputs get larger (`sum` is a [Schlemiel the Painter's algorithm](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Joel_Spolsky#Schlemiel_the_Painter.27s_algorithm) when used with sequences).

Answer (score 0):

This function can convert listWidgets item into single tuple and also convert multiple element of tuple into single element tuple : Used for Sqlite3 and data query from listwidgets.

```
def tuple_converter(self,item):
        target = ''
        for i in item:
            target += i + " " 
        target = target.rstrip()
        target = tuple(target.split(","))
        return target
#syntax  name = tuple_converter(tuple((item).split()))
```

'''